# Multiple values for variable without tuple - Python

Tags: python, variables, stream

I am accessing a stream from an API, the stream takes only 1 value to identify which instrument I would like to return data for.  I am trying to retrieve multiple values from the same stream using the same variable, tuples do not seem to work, for instance:

```
  instrument = "EUR_USD"                    #returns one price stream
  instrument = ("EUR_USD", "GBP_USD")       #only returns the stream for the last entry.
```

I've also tried:

```
  pair_list = ('EUR_USD','GBP_USD')
  instrument =''.join(pair_list)
```

which does not seem to work as well..

How could I send both values so that I get results from both instruments?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer to this question would depend on API details that you haven't told us and which we can't deduce from the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

As the API only accepts one value, you are going to have to make two requests, one request for each value.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I made a mistake in my code and this does seem to work:

```
  pair_list = ('EUR_USD','GBP_USD')
  instruments =','.join(pair_list)
```

I missed a comma......